# Еще об ударении

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

Как правильно говорить "п**о**д воду" или "под в**о**ду"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Орфоэпический словарь под.ред Аванесова дает оба варианта пОд воду и под вОду.